# Slowdown issue in web project

Tags: asp.net

I just need suggestion in this case. There is a PIN code field in my project in asp.net environment. I have stored 50,000 around pin code in sql server database. When I run project in local host, it becomes slow down. Since I have a drop-down to get value from database. I think it is because of huge data is being rendered into html, since when I click on view source at run-time, I can see all the PIN-code inside it. 
Moreover, I have also done this for Select CITY, and STATE from database in a same way.

I will really appreciate you, if you get me any logic or technique to lessen this slowdown

Comment: You have to use something like paging, means dont show all pins at a time, you should show pins based on selected city or state.

Comment: Well dear, I am creating a job portal project, where company will select the pin code for job location. Further, I don't want to get any city on the basis of selected pin code. I have a drop down that is getting value from sql server database. I have never seen any site which gives selecting pin code in paging way.

Comment: You can do one thing, I think pins will not be selected from dropdowns. Imagine your chosen pincode at last 50000th postion and you have to scroll down to that. Dont use dropdowns, use textbox instead and ask user to input pins in that textbox and do further operation based on that pin.

Comment: Yes, Your are right. Now I am dropping idea of drop down for this. But yes, there is no need to scroll-down till the 50000th position in drop down list box in asp.net, since there is auto-fill type selection option. You will just type pin code there, and it will automatically bring that pin code for selection. But again thanks for your idea.

Comment: Welcome, you can use `jQuery UI autocomplete` for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using all the Pincode in the single page then You have multiple option to optimized this slow down If this is in initialized phase then Try MongoDB ,No SQL DB otherwise go for Solr , Redis that gives fast accessing of the data. If you are not able to using these then You can optimised it by eager loading , Cache Storing of data.

If its not in single page then break it to batch via paginate the pincode.

Comment: Well dear, I am creating a job portal project, where company will select the pin code for job location. Further, I don't want to get any city on the basis of selected pin code. I have a drop down that is getting value from sql server database. I have never seen any site which gives selecting pin code in paging way.

Comment: You can use JS Libraries for it if pincode from usa then it will be easily available

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem with any website where we deal with large amount of data. To be frank there is no code level solution for this. You need to select any of following approach.

You can try multiple options for faster retrieval.

1. **Caching -**

Use  redis or memcache - in simpler words, on the first request cache manager will read and store your data from SQL server. For subsequent requests, data will be served from cache.

Also, don't forget to make a provision to invalidate the data when new pin codes are added.

**Edit**: You can also use object caching provided by .Net framework. [Refer: object caching](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_caching.htm)

Code will be something like.

```
if (Cache["key_pincodes"] == null)
{
    // if No object is present in Cache, add it to the cache with expiry time of 10 minutes
    // Read data to datatable or any object
    DataTable pinCodeObject = GetPinCodesFromdatabase();
    Cache.Insert("key_pincodes", pinCodeObject, null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
}
else // If pinCodes are cached, dont make Database call and read it from cache
{
    // This will get execute
    DataTable pinCodeObject = (DataTable)Cache["key_pincodes"];
}
// bind it your dropdown
```

2. **No-sql database-**
   MongoDB, XML, Txt files could be used to read the data. It will take much lesser time than the database hit.

Comment: Can you provide me code using caching technique with invalid option for new entered pin code. Please

Comment: @RavindraBisht: I've added code. Hope it helps you.